# Typescript: typing an object with dynamic properties

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

I want to loop an array to create an object.

input:

```
const input = [{email:email1, name: name1},{email:email2, name: name2}, {email:email3, name: name3}]
```

Desired output:

```
const output = {email1: name1, email2: name2, email3: name3
}
```

In javascript, I wrote

```
 let output = input.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
                return (acc[cur.email] = cur.name)
            }, {})
```

But I got a typing error saying obj cannot have a string property. How should I type this function properly?

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: in your first input, are `emailX` and `nameX` variables?  If not then they are undefined when reading the value.

Comment: emailX, nameX represent string, not variables. Titian's answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more explicit about the type of the result, typescript will not know that `{}` is supposed to be an object with any keys strings and string values:

```
const input = [{ email: 'email1', name: 'name1' }, { email: 'email2', name: 'name2' }, { email: 'email3', name: 'name3' }]
let output = input.reduce<Record<string, string>>((acc, cur, i) => {
    acc[cur.email] = cur.name
    return acc;
}, {})
```

Note: Also you need to return `acc` from the reducer function.